# iOS Simulator on Mac with Ethernet & WiFi

Tags: wifi, ios-simulator

I am working on a Mac that has an Ethernet connection to a LAN and the Internet.  I have an iOS application that I am running in the simulator that needs to connect to a WiFi network in another office.  I turned on Airport and connected to the WiFi network I need, but I don't know if the simulator is using the Ethernet or Wifi connection to communicate.  I looked for settings in the simulator and couldn't find a way to tell it to use the WiFi connection exclusively.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coworker answered this question for me today.  Apparently, the iOS simulator does not do WiFi.  It only knows about a network connection.  He said the simulator simply reports that there's a connection, but it's not WiFi.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess iOS Simulator uses whatever network connection is available tot the Computer it is running on. If there are multiple Connections it should scan both IP ranges... I don't exactly know how it handles the case both ip ranges are the same... This is (even if possible) no good solution, because you never exactly know if there are multiple devices with the same IP...